# Neo4J Cypher: filter out variable length paths by criteria

Tags: neo4j, cypher, variable-length

How could I imply restrictions on variable length path?

I have all possible paths from some `start` node query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :NODE(id)
MATCH all_paths_from_Start = (start:Person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person)
WHERE start.id = 128 AND start.country <> "Uganda"
RETURN paths;
```

No I want filter out all paths which have at least two persons with the same `country`. *How could I do that?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Get an array of countries to the path with possible duplicates: `REDUCE`

2) Remove duplicates and compare the sizes of arrays: `UNWIND` + `COLLECT(DISTINCT...)`

```
MATCH path = (start:Person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person)
      WHERE start.id = 128 AND start.country <> "Uganda"
WITH path, 
     REDUCE(acc=[], n IN NODES(path) | acc + n.country) AS countries
     UNWIND countries AS country
WITH path, 
     countries, COLLECT(DISTINCT country) AS distinctCountries
     WHERE SIZE(countries) = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

P.S. `REDUCE` can be replaced by `EXTRACT` (thanks to Gabor Szarnyas):

```
MATCH path = (start:Person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person)
      WHERE start.id = 128 AND start.country <> "Uganda"
WITH path, 
     EXTRACT(n IN NODES(path) | n.country) AS countries
     UNWIND countries AS country
WITH path, 
     countries, COLLECT(DISTINCT country) AS distinctCountries
     WHERE SIZE(countries) = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

P.P.S. Thanks again to Gabor Szarnyas for another idea for simplifying the query:

```
MATCH path = (start:Person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person)
      WHERE start.id = 128 AND start.country <> "Uganda"
WITH path
     UNWIND NODES(path) AS person
WITH path, 
     COLLECT(DISTINCT person.country) as distinctCountries
     WHERE LENGTH(path) + 1 = SIZE(distinctCountries)
RETURN path
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Will it be the best choice from performance perspective? I will have a very big dataset, with up to million of  nodes. Is there any way to make the query faster?

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk The heaviest part of the query is the first `MATCH`: `MATCH path = (start:Person)-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person) WHERE start.id = 128 AND start.country <> "Uganda"`. Currently there are not quite understand how to improve it ...

Comment: at least I can index `id` and `coutnry`. Pls let me know if you will have any ideas

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk The `id` and the `country`, of course, be sure to be indexed.

Comment: @stdob-- I think we might get along without `extract`: `UNWIND NODES(path) AS node WITH path, COLLECT(node.country) AS countries, COLLECT(DISTINCT node.country) AS distinctCountries` I'm not sure if it will have a measurable effect on performance, but it may be easier to read.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas Yes you are right. Added an option based on your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

One solution that I can think of is to get the [`nodes`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-nodes) of the path, and for each person on the path, [`extract`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-extract) the value of the number of persons from the same country (which we determine by [`filter`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#functions-filter)ing for the same country. A path has persons from unique countries if it has zero persons from the same country, i.e. for all persons, there is only a single person (the person himself/herself) from that country.

```
MATCH p = (start:Person {id: 128})-[:FRIENDSHIP*1..20]->(person:Person)
WHERE start.country <> "Uganda"
WITH p, nodes(p) AS persons
WITH p, extract(p1 IN persons | size(filter(p2 IN persons WHERE p1.country = p2.country))) AS personsFromSameCountry
WHERE length(filter(p3 IN personsFromSameCountry WHERE p3 > 1)) = 0
RETURN p
```

The query is syntactically correct but I didn't test it on any data.

Note that I moved the `id = 128` condition to the pattern and shortened the `all_paths_from_Start` variable as `p`.